# Mathematica crashed on EMF export

Tags: export, windows, crash

Here's the code to reproduce an error.

First I generate a bar chart:

```
expr = BarChart[{1, 1, 2}]
pic = First@ImportString[ExportString[expr, "PDF"]]
filename = "img.emf"
```

(the "pic" operation is necessary to preserve formatting when exporting to EMF - I've found this solution here on MMa.SE)

Than I try to export it:

```
Export[filename <> ".emf", pic, ImageResolution -> 4100]
```

Large `ImageResolution` is a trick to make *Mathematica* export a vector EMF - another trick I picked up on MMa.SE.

The `Export` crashes *Mathematica* kernel. This bug seems to be `BarChart` specific, as I cannot reproduce is if a swap `BarChart` for `ListPlot`.

I use the newest - 11th version. 
Any suggestion on how to fix it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce because Linux, but svg works fine `Export["img.svg", pic, ImageResolution -> 4100]`, svg is closely analogous to emf.

Comment: @Feyre, I'm on Win7 x64. My purpose is to use it as image in Word and svg is not supported. Additionally I have no problems with this routine in mma 10.

Comment: Then I don't think there's much you can do except register this with support as a bug, considering the upvotes one would assume three people reproduced the issue.

Comment: I'm on Win7 x64 but I don't get the crash with version 11.0.0 and the exported EMF file contains rasterized version of the figure.

Comment: It appears the trick to make Mathematica export an vector EMF no longer works in Mma 11.  On Win 10 Mma 11 produced a 749 MB EMF and caused all kinds of hang problems requiring a hard reboot.  A small EMF (without the ImageResolution specified) was produced without a problem (except for not being a vector graphic).

Comment: Unfortunately I think your workaround will have to be to export as a PDF from 11, import the PDF in version 10, and export the EMF from there. At least, until this bug is fixed.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, thanks for your suggestion. I need the vector file so can't drop the ImageResolution...

Comment: @ChrisDegnen, thanks for reproducing this glitch! Hopefully this helps attract more attention to this bug.

Comment: @OleksandrR., thanks for your suggestion! However I need the ability to export EMFs routinely and there're no major features in the new version that I would need... So I'm probably skipping this update until more stable version is available..

Comment: @EkaterinaUrakova I didn't dropped `ImageResolution -> 4100` during my test. I strongly suspect that the result depends on the graphical card (mine is an old ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series).

Comment: I have successfully used ".eps" as a vector graphics format for export to MS Word.  Inside Word they looked dreadful, but on export of the final document to PDF, you wouldn't know that MS had been anyway near them.

Comment: @mikado, thanks! will definitely try: I've tried to paste them into Word and they definitely looked substandard.. Now will try to export to pdf.

Comment: Not solved in 11.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the crash with versions 10.4.1, 11.0.1 and 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64: both with `ImageResolution` and without it I get the same EMF file with rasterized plot in it. The common way to avoid rasterization is to remove the `Opacity` directives:

```
plot = BarChart[{1, 1, 2}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] /. _Opacity -> (## &[]);
Export[filename <> ".emf", plot]
```

Now `plot` is correctly exported as EMF in the all mentioned versions without rasterization.