# EMF Export Bug in v12

Tags: bugs, export, charts, version-12

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier**

For some reason EMF vector image export deteriorates with every version.

In v12.0 for Windows create a simple BarChart:

```
x = Range@3
b = (BarChart[{x, x}] )
```

Attempt to Export it to EMF:

```
Export["emfsaga.emf", b]
```

This produces a rasterized version, which is an [issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65509/barchart-rasterized-in-emf-export) known for 5 years to the community.

Okay, use the 'huge ImageResolution' trick to force vector output, which was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396898/why-do-barchart-graphics-exported-from-mathematica-have-pixelated-text-is-there/7561608#7561608) and [discusses](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31255/setting-non-standard-imageresolution-for-emf-export-as-default) as a solution almost 10 year ago:

```
Export["emfsaga.emf", b, ImageResolution -> 8000]
```

Which worked previously, but now produces the chart which only displays part of the BarChart:

[image]

Older  [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125150/mathematica-crashed-on-emf-export) which relied on removing Opacity no longer works.

What is the new way to properly export EMF in v12?

**update 2019-05-21**
I'm slightly hesitant posting this because posting any solution to the EMF export problem results in the latter being made ineffective in the future versions of Mathematica.

So if you desperately need to output EMF (like me) then one way is

- Install Inkscape
- Export charts as pdf
- Convert PDFs to EMFs for example with this functions

```
InkscapeConvert[path_]:=Module[{
    inkpath="\"C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\inkscape.exe\"",
    command
    },
        Run["\"" <> inkpath <> " -f=\""<>path<>".pdf\"" <> " --export-emf=\""<>path<>".emf\"\""]

]
```

The limitations is that Inkscape does not properly handle Opacity/transparency.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] when posting new questions (please read the tag description). I assume that if you are confident you found a bug, you already reported it to Wolfram?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I'm pretty sure, yes. Already reporting - but it is basically futile. I've already done that several times (the export to EMF is broken since v11) with no results except for lengthy email exchanges.

Comment: reported to support

Comment: if it is relevant case number is 3935055

Comment: You can flatten transparency using Illustrator as I explain here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32948/280

Comment: The [trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140442/280) with removing `Opacity` still works for me with version 12.0 on Windows 7 x64.